# MySQL PDO Query not showing procedure out variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to get an out variable with a procedure in my PDO setup. I am getting an empty array();

```
      $connection->query('
       drop procedure if exists relatives;
       create procedure relatives(in parent int(11),out counted int(11))
       begin
        set @counted=1;
       end;
      ');
      $fetch=$connection->query('call relatives(1,@counted); select @counted as c;')->fetchall();
```